# Password in db2 Connection string

Tags: asp.net, db2

My application needs connection to both sql server and DB2 server. DB2 is running on Linux servers. So it has LDAP mode of authentication. Now connection string for sql server is saved in Web.config file....but connection string for DB2 is dynamic and is in code behind page as it requires LDAP id and password supplied by user as parameters. 
please help me in solving how to securely pass the password given by user in the DB2 dynamic connection string?

Comment: Is your issue "how to securely pass the password given by user in the db2 dynamic connection string"? Have you connected OK but now just want to secure the credentials?

Comment: Yes..exactly....connection is all well and fine.....issue is passing password securely

Comment: passing or storing? if passing is an issue, the usual solution is use an SSL connection. If storing is an issue, where is it currently stored?

Comment: @ElectricLlama ..user inputs the password....nd it's stored in a variable nd passed to connection string as a value to pwd parameter of connection string....

Comment: and the security issue is you don't want someone to intercept it when it is sent to DB2? It appears the password is not stored anywhere (only temporarily in memory in a variable) or is the issue that you don't want a user to have to type a password in?

Comment: @ElectricLlama yes..One thing is wen it's saved in a variable in memory how much it's susceptible to password hack and another thing is don't want someone to intercept it when sent to db2....btr if sum encryption possible......

Comment: To encrypt communication, use SSL. To protect runtime data on your web server, make sure your web server is 'hardened' as per IIS documents and make sure your web code is secure (i.e. URL injection). I think this question is a little too broad. Why don't you start doing some research on SSL and ask some specific questions.

Comment: @ElectricLlama  thanks for your time....yes will do it..